# ASP.NET Core 3.1 select tag return null

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, html-select

I'm trying to get data from a form when submitted and save it into SQL database, but I have a problem with the select tag when submit clicked it returns a null value to `[HttpPost]` action.

I tried every solution on the web but got no answer...

Please help me...

My code is:

**DbContext**

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Employee> Employee { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Coding> Coding { get; set; }
}
```

**Employee** model:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string NationalCode { get; set; }
    public Coding City { get; set; }
}
```

**Coding** model:

```
public class Coding
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

**Home** controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Create()
{
    var cityList = _dbContext.Coding.ToList();
    ViewBag.city = cityList;

    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create(Employee employee)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _employeeRepository.AddEmployee(employee);
        return View();
    }

    return View();
}
```

**Create.cshtml** view:

```
@model Emp.Models.Employee
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers



<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Create" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label asp-for="Name"></label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input asp-for="Name" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label asp-for="NationalCode"></label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input asp-for="NationalCode" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label asp-for="City"></label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select asp-for="City"
                            asp-items=@(new SelectList(ViewBag.city , "Id", "City"))
                            class="custom-select">
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help

Would you please give me an example of a ViewModel with my defined classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `asp-for="City.Id"` in the select tag:

```
<select asp-for="City.Id"
        asp-items=@(new SelectList(ViewBag.city , "Id", "City"))
        class="custom-select">
</select>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should use ViewModel or add new property that could be `CityId` instead of using `Coding` class for `City`

Comment: Would you please give me an example of a viewmodel that contains my classes?